# Facebook API get reviews

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to programming and new to Facebook.

I am trying to get the ratings (recommendations) from my Facebook business page.

I have my UserID and my AccessToken.

When I try this Get request: `https://graph.facebook.com/{userID}/ratings?access_token={access_Token}` I get the following error:

```
"error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (ratings) on node type (User)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "{I removed this}"
    }
```

It seems this is because I'm logged in with my user profile, and there are no ratings for teh profile, only the business.

If I try: `https://graph.facebook.com/{userID}/posts?access_token={access_token}` I see all the posts I made as my FB profile, but not as my business page.

How is it possible to login as my business page so I can get the UserID and AccessToken so I can use them?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a User Token, but you need a Page Token of your Page. With that User Token, you can create a Page Token by using the following endpoint: `/me/accounts?fields=access_token`

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/